# How to enable using Bunifu.Framework.UI Visual Studio 2019

Tags: bunifu

I can't understand why using Bunifu is not installed.Framework.UI; and using windowsformscontrolllibrary1;
All graphics programs don't work in my Visual Studio 2019

Tell me how to solve this problem for me

[Mistake](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzYha.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ea2j6.png)

Comment: I bet the error message in Russian gives you a big hint about why it doesn't work. Hint 1 : Type the error message in your favorite search engine. Hint 2 : Set your visual studio in English, so you'll get the English versions of the errors and will have way more results

Comment: the search engine did not give a solution

Severity Code Description Project File String Suppression Status
Error CS0246 The type or namespace name "Bunifu" could not be found (perhaps the using directive or assembly reference is missing)